# WSO2 SP manager does not save the rule in worker / resource node

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have set up a two node worker and a single node manager WSO2 SP cluster.
But when i push my rule to manager , It seems to deploy it in worker node as it prints out log **"Siddhi app siddhi-app-name-1 of siddhi-app-name-1 successfully deployed in ResourceNode { id: wso2-sp-worker-33-123, host: 10.112.33.123, port: 9090 }**. but when i look into the wso2/worker/deplyment/siddhi-files in 10.112.33.123 it does not show up.

So where does it get deployed?

```
 my query is as follows:

  @App:name("siddhi-app-name-1")
  @App:description("rule for siddhi-app-name-1")

  @source(
       type="kafka",topic.list="input-topic",
       group.id="group1",threading.option="single.thread",
       bootstrap.servers="<list of kafka brokers>",
       @map(type="json"))
  define stream inputstream (tag_id string, tag_type int, timestamp long, value double, quality int, datatype string);

  @sink(
      type="kafka",
      topic="output-topic",
      bootstrap.servers="<list of kafka brokers>",
      @map(type="json"))
  Define stream outputstream (message string);

  @dist(execGroup="group1")
  from inputstream[name=="penta"]
  select tag_id as message
  insert into outputstream;'
```

Comment: but when i start the other worker node  and then push the siddhi sql it shows up in its corresponding siddhi-files folder of worker

Comment: Location you are mentioning is accurate. Can you please check the logs of 10.112.33.123 and verify whether it prints a log saying app is deployed.